# What do negative values in the output matrices of FeatureHasher mean?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I expected all values in the output sparse matrices of `FeatureHasher` to be non-negative because I thought it should just count the term frequencies and index the terms with the help of a hashing function. When collision happens, I expect it to just add up the frequencies of the 'collided terms'. However, it seems I was wrong since it in fact outputted a bunch of negative values, given a list of dictionary with terms as keys and term frequencies as values.

What exactly do negative values mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input values were all positive (term frequencies), then the negative values don't actually mean anything. Citing the [scikit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#feature-hashing):

> Since the hash function might cause collisions between (unrelated) features, a signed hash function is used and the sign of the hash value determines the sign of the value stored in the output matrix for a feature. This way, collisions are likely to cancel out rather than accumulate error, and the expected mean of any output feature’s value is zero.

The Wikipedia has a [little table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing#Feature_vectorization_using_the_hashing_trick) showing the effect of this scheme, which was invented by [Weinberger et al.](http://alex.smola.org/papers/2009/Weinbergeretal09.pdf). Not only does it alleviate the effect of collisions, but it makes your features behave more like Gaussians, which helps some learning algorithms.

If you want to get rid of the negative values, then pass `non_negative=True` to the `FeatureHasher` constructor. The implementation of that option is a bit of a hack, but it makes tf-idf and naive Bayes work again.